# Using googlemaps api, places_nearby to find locations nearby with a certain keyword

Tags: python, google-maps

Using the googlemaps api, I'm trying to get the "gyms" near a certain location:

After importing googlemaps api and typing my user key:

```
client = googlemaps.Client(key)

latlon = ' [atitude, longitude'

nearby = client.places_nearby(latlon, keyword="gym", radius = 100)

print (nearby)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dd/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/file.py", line 11, in <module>
    nearby = client.places_nearby(latlon, keyword="gym", radius = 100)
  File "C:\Users\dd\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\googlemaps\client.py", line 365, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dd\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\googlemaps\places.py", line 249, in places_nearby
    rank_by=rank_by, type=type, page_token=page_token)
  File "C:\Users\dd\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\googlemaps\places.py", line 342, in _places
    return client._request(url, params)
  File "C:\Users\dd\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\googlemaps\client.py", line 270, in _request
    extract_body, requests_kwargs, post_json)
  File "C:\Users\dd\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\googlemaps\client.py", line 270, in _request
    extract_body, requests_kwargs, post_json)
  File "C:\Users\dd\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\googlemaps\client.py", line 270, in _request
    extract_body, requests_kwargs, post_json)
  [Previous line repeated 7 more times]
  File "C:\Users\dd\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\googlemaps\client.py", line 210, in _request
    raise googlemaps.exceptions.Timeout()
googlemaps.exceptions.Timeout
```

Comment: Do you need a `]` at the end of your `latlon` string declaration?

Comment: I think the `]` should be `l` so it says `latitude`, its part of the string.

Comment: Is `latlon = ' [atitude, longitude'` part of your code, or do you have actual coordinates there, like `latlon = '123.4, -32.3'`?